# gradlew exited with non-zero code: 1 in viro react

Tags: android, react-native, augmented-reality, gradlew, viro-react

I followed every steps from [this](https://viro-community.readme.io/docs/installation-instructions) documentation. But when I run the expo app following errors showed up.
[image]

I am suffering from this problem since 1 week. Please Help.

Answer (score 0):

It could be because react-viro has "peerDependencies": "react-native": "0.65.1".

I am trying expo version 44.0.0 because it uses react-native version    0.64.3.

Also, React-viro requires the deprecated jcenter() repository in the build.gradle for support of exoplayer 2.7.1 which viro uses. This has been removed from newer versions of react-native. It can manually be added:

android/build.gradle

```
...
 buildscript
  { repositories
    {
      jcenter() // <- Add this line
...
 allprojects
  {
    repositories
      {
        jcenter() // <- Add this line
```

Answer (score -1):

I tried the following steps

- rm -rf yarn.lock node_modules .expo package-lock.json
- yarn install
- expo upgrade

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34817759)